# How do I use for loop for more then one UILabels

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, uilabel

I have 10 UILabel called label1, label2....label10 in my app. My question is how to use for loop to access this UILabels. Please any one help me. Thanks.

Comment: Please share some code. And what does this have to do with `xcode4.2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Find the following information in my answer:

**--->Adding 10 Labels(Using For Loop As per you query) in a method in a class**

**--->Retrieving the above added 10 Labels(Using For Loop As per you query) in any method with in the same class**

***Step1:***

**->Adding 10 Labels(Using For Loop As per you query) in a method(Ex: in '-viewDidLoad'  method) in a class**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    int LabelX=25;
    int LabelY=50;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        UILabel *sampleLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(LabelX, LabelY, 150, 25)];
        //   Label.text=[anArray objectAtIndex:i];
        sampleLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
        sampleLabel.tag=i+1;
        [self.view addSubview:sampleLabel];
       LabelY+=30;
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
 }
```

***Step2:***

**->Retrieving the above added 10 Labels(Using For Loop As per you query) in any method (Ex: in '-retrive' method) with in the same class**

```
-(void)retrive
{
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    UILabel *retrivedLabel=(UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:i+1];
    //Here your 10 labels will be retrived one by one...
    //Do what ever you want with these labels.....Ex: Print the text in label, change the frame of it, change the background color of it,etc....

    //Getting the text
    NSLog(@"-->%@<--",retrivedLabel.text);

    //Getting tag
    NSLog(@"-->%ld<--",(long)retrivedLabel.tag);

    //Removing label
    [retrivedLabel removeFromSuperview];
}
}
```

I Hope it will help you...

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on no shared code.

```
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
[label1 setTag:1]; // Assign the label number to tag, so label2 `setTag:` would be 2 - I suppose this isn't really needed but could help in the future development.
// Do this for however many UILabels you need.

// One way could be to put them into an array.
NSArray *labelArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:label1, label2,...., nil]; // ..... being the other UILabels you want to add.
```

at this point you have two for loops you can use.

The first one is a `foreach loop`

```
for(UILabel *label in labelArray) {
    // This will loop through all the objects in labelArray
    // Do whatever you want with that label here.
}
```

The second options is a normal `for loop`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [labelArray count]; i++) {
    // This will enter a loop for the number of objects (count) in labelArray.
    // But we need to actually retrieve the object from the array still.
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[labelArray objectAtIndex:i];
    // I suppose you could also do some checks to make sure that the object being returned is actually a UILabel.
    // because `objectAtIndex:` will return `id` not `UILabel` I have just cast the object to `UILabel`.
}
```

If you need anything more please ask or share code.